# Not Responding window when browser is loading + Text is not changing

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, tkinter, selenium-chromedriver

Why the root window is not responding while browser is loading...?

Is it a bug from my code or it happens for all?

Can it be resolved?

If yes, How?

[image]

My Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from time import sleep
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import time
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox

root = Tk()
frame = Frame(root)
labelText = StringVar()
display = Label(frame, textvariable=labelText)
labelText.set("Connecting to the server...")
display.pack()
frame.pack()
display.update()

def change_root_label(message):
    labelText.set(message)
    display.pack()
    frame.pack()

change_root_label("Opening...") #updated code for updating question
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://google.com')
change_root_label("Opened...")


root.mainloop()
```

Why the text `Opening..` is not displayed?

Comment: Any command in a thread is executed when the previous one is terminated. Your program has only one thread (the main thread), thus your problem. have a look on [multithreading](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm)

Comment: I have just updated the question for a minor solution having question exactly on the same question...

Comment: you really need to check how threads works: your question is too broad right now, it will be a great effort from someone to answer. For a better understanding, start with removing the *noise*: since we suppose our problem is related to when each command is executed and how much it takes, try to replace all the task related to selenium with a sleep time, and look what happens to the GUI

Answer (score 0):

Changing your function `change_root_label` to this should solve your problem:

```
def change_root_label(message):
    labelText.set(message)
    display.update()
```

Remember you don't need to pack your widgets again unless you want to change their packing(position in its parent). In your code `display.update()` was called after you set the value to `"Connecting to the server..."`, but after changing the value to `'Opening...'` you have to call update or mainloop function to update your UI. So in your code when mainloop is called at end, it will update your label twice but very fast so you do not see the text `'Opening...'`.